# Evaluation of Infinite Series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Using the fact that

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} = \log 2$, then evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n(n+1)}$.

I tried using partial fractions by splitting $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ into $\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}$ and applied summation, multiplied $(-1)^{n+1}$ on both sides, therefore applying the fact given, in the first integrand and then how to proceed? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have everything you need:
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n(n+1)}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)=(-\log 2)+(1-\log 2)=\color{red}{1-\log 4}. $$

Comment: can you please explain the second term (1-log 2).

Comment: @SamChristopher: it is the same series as $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$, minus the very first term.

Comment: oh...yes..Thank you..that did not strike me..

Answer (score 2):

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n(n+1)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)}=-\ln(2)+(-\ln(2)+1)
$$